# Regency of πίνω in Anacreon's ode Πάντα πίνει

Tags: greek, ancient-greek

The following poem is from the Odes of Anacreon:

> ἡ γῆ μέλαινα πίνει,
> Πίνει δὲ δένδρε’ αὐτήν
> Πίνει θάλασσα δ’αὔρας,
> Ὁ δ’ἤλιος θάλασσαν,
> Τὸν δ’ἤλιον σελήνη.
> Τί μοι μάχεσθ’ ἑτῖροι,
> Καὐτῷ θέλοντι πίνειν;

If I understood it correctly, verses 3, 4 and 5 can be translated roughly as:

> the sea drinks the breeze,
> the sun drinks the sea,
> the moon drinks the sun.

What I don't understand is that in verses 4 and 5 the regency of πίνω seems to be accusative, but in verse 3 αὔρα appears in the genitive.

What's going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

αὔρας is accusative *plural*: "the sea drinks the *breezes*." (And in Anacreon's poetic dialect, I think that he would have the genitive singular as -ης. -ας after ρ is Attic.)